# how to update a cached get request in angular

Tags: angularjs, watch

i just want to know how and where can i use $watch to update a data that i received with  http get request with cache:true option.i just started working with angular.

---

service :

```
app.factory('customer', ['$http',function($http){  
    var obj = {};
    var baseUrl="../controller/customer.php";
    obj.fetchCustomers= function(){ 

        var config={
            cache: true
        }
        return $http.get(baseUrl +'?type=getAll',config);
    }   
    obj.editCustomer=function(customerInfo){
        return $http.post(baseUrl,{data:customerInfo ,type:'edit'});
    }
 return obj;
}]);
```

controller that receive data :

```
customer.fetchCustomers().success(function(data){
        $rootScope.customers=data.getAll;
    })
```

controller that edit data :

```
  $scope.editCustomer=function(){
            customer.editCustomer($scope.customerInfo).success(function(data){
                if(data.error=true){
                    $location.path("/accounting/viewCustomer");
                }else{
                    $scope.alert="wrong";
                }
            })
        };
```

it work fine but my view wont update when i update data

Comment: it's not really clear what issue you are having here.  If you are having issues with your view updating, we would need to see the view to help troubleshoot it.  Beyond that, why would your `editCustomer` callback redirect you when there *is* an error, and tell you it is "wrong" when there *isn't an error?  that doesn't make much sense.  Also, you should use `.then()` rather than `.success()`, since `.success()` is deprecated.

Comment: my issue is when editcontroller update database , view still showing previous data  that is chached

Comment: right, that much is clear, but we don't know why the view is showing any data at all, because ***we have no view code here***.

Comment: there is no logic in view  only a ng-repeat  that loop in $rootScope.customers object

Comment: ok, but you aren't changing the `$rootScope.customers` object with your `editCustomer` function, so how would that function update a view of `$rootScope.customers` data?

Comment: i have a customer table in my database that i retrieve all of it in $rootScope.customers and edit function update one row of that table and redirect to view

Comment: right, but your edit function doesn't tell the rest of your angular app that you've updated a row on the server, and you aren't requesting an update from the server at any point in the code here, so your app has no way at all of knowing that a new row is there.  Angular doesn't just poll the server to see if there is any new data, it has to be told to check.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131961/discussion-between-rwin-and-claies).